# Авторизация через фейсбук

Tags: oauth, facebook

Проблема в том, что мое приложение не может получить поле `email` от сервера фейсбук. Раньше все было норм. Может кто сталкивался?

**UPD**

Запрашиваю по адресу

> https://graph.facebook.com/

Использую `access_token`.

Для простоты, из ответа дергаю три поля:

1. first_name
2. last_name
3. email

Почта в ответе не приходит.

Comment: (сарказм)У меня была похожая проблема, решил тем что задал вопрос с большим количеством данных.(/сарказм)

Answer (score 1):

У меня сложилась подобная ситуация, правда я с фэйсбуком работаю через Loginza, так вот Loginza, хоть и имеет поле e-mail, для пользователей с фэйсбука его не возвращает... знаю вывод, конечно, косвенный, но, вероятно, он вообще его не возвращает.